# Interpolation of a gray scale image in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, interpolation

[image: Gray Scale Image with Empty Black area]

I want to fill the black areas with the value of neighboring pixels. Kind of interpolation. Can any one suggest me how Can I do in matlab.

Comment: Duplicate on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11338164/769220

Comment: This is technically on-topic, but it's an exact duplicate of a question on SO that already has a better answer (by the same user), so I'm closing it here.  It's also a little more oriented towards MATLAB programming than DSP concepts, so it's only borderline on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `imfill` function, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imfill.html

Comment: imfill fills with only one color. please suggest some other methods

Comment: Then to fill one black area, try to identify a sub-region containing the black area first, then creates a Delaunay triangulation of the non-black points in inside the sub-region. It will allow you to do the interpolation at the black points.

Comment: please explain in detail about what to do after I create the Delaunay Triangulation of non-black points. I can Identify the sub-Regions containing black area

Comment: see my answer on stackoverflow